# iOS 6.0 simulator disappeared

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm not able to test my app on iOS 6.0 simulator, because it disappeared. I definitely remember I downloaded it and for some time I could use it. When I click on more simulators to download it now, there is only iOS 7.0 and iOS 6.1 simulators. And for all I know, I have set the deployment target to 6.0 everywhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Apple withdrew the 6.0 simulator at the server end, so it is no longer listed. If you really want it, you can move it into Xcode from another version of Xcode (it's obvious where it goes).

Answer (score 1):

The latest Xcode (5.1 as of writing this) only supports iOS 6.1 simulator. If you wish to test on iOS 6.0, you need to test on a device.

Technically speaking, there is very little API difference between 6.0 and 6.1, so you can test 6.1 for most scenarios just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Still we can use ios 6 simulator in xcode 5.1.

> If you cant see iOS 6 simulator in downloads. Try this one,
>
> download **xcode 4** sdk and copy the **ios 6 simulator sdk** from xcode4,
>   [Application->xcode 4 ->contents->developer->platforms->iphone
>   simulator platform->developer->sdk folder.]
>
> And paste **ios 6 simulator** sdk to **xcode 5**, [Application->xcode5->
>   contents->developer->platforms->iphonesimulator
>   platform->developer->sdk folder]

I followed this steps and got ios 6 simulator,. see below

[image]

Comment: This is incorrect and is also not an answer but a comment. Did you read the question? He says the simulator does not appear in the Downloads section.

Comment: So, as per answer, we cant use ios6 simulator in xcode 5.1? @LeoNatan

Comment: You can use iOS 6.1 simulator.